# Special kind of row-by-row multiplication of 2 sparse matrices in Python

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

What I'm looking for: a way to implement in Python a special multiplication operation for matrices that happen to be in scipy sparse ([csr](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html)) format. This is a special kind of multiplication, not matrix multiplication nor [Kronecker multiplication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product) nor [Hadamard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard_product_(matrices)) aka [pointwise](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.multiply) multiplication, and does not seem to have any built-in support in scipy.sparse.

The desired operation: Each row of the output should contain the results of every product of the elements of the corresponding rows in the two input matrices. So starting with two identically sized matrices, each with dimensions *m* by *n*, the result should have dimensions *m* by *n^2*.

It looks like this:

[image: graphic of desired multiplication operation]

Python code:

```
import scipy.sparse
A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,2],[3,4]]))
B = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[0,5],[6,7]]))

# C is the desired product of A and B. It should look like:
C = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[0,5,0,10],[18,21,24,28]]))
```

What would be a nice or efficient way to do this? I've tried looking here on stackoverflow as well as elsewhere, with no luck so far. So far it sounds like my best bet is to do a row by row operation in a for loop, but that sounds horrendous seeing as **my input matrices have a few million rows and few thousand columns, mostly sparse**.

Comment: Noted this questions is asked in 2014, I am wondering if there is new solutions now...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example, `C` is the first and last row of `kron`

```
In [4]: A=np.array([[1,2],[3,4]])
In [5]: B=np.array([[0,5],[6,7]])
In [6]: np.kron(A,B)
Out[6]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
       [ 6,  7, 12, 14],
       [ 0, 15,  0, 20],
       [18, 21, 24, 28]])
In [7]: np.kron(A,B)[[0,3],:]
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
       [18, 21, 24, 28]])
```

`kron` contains the same values as `np.outer`, but they are in a different order.

For large dense arrays, `einsum` might provide good speed:

```
np.einsum('ij,ik->ijk',A,B).reshape(A.shape[0],-1)
```

`sparse.kron` does the same thing as the `np.kron`:

```
As = sparse.csr_matrix(A); Bs ...
sparse.kron(As,Bs).tocsr()[[0,3],:].A
```

`sparse.kron` is written in Python, so you probably could modify it if it is doing unnecessary calculations.

An iterative solution appears to be:

```
sparse.vstack([sparse.kron(a,b) for a,b in zip(As,Bs)]).A
```

Being iterative I don't expect it to be faster than paring down the full `kron`.  But short of digging into the logic of `sparse.kron` it is probably the best I can do.

`vstack` uses `bmat`, so the calculation is:

```
sparse.bmat([[sparse.kron(a,b)] for a,b in zip(As,Bs)])
```

But `bmat` is rather complex, so it won't be easy to simplify this further.

The `np.einsum` solution can't be easily extended to sparse - there isn't a `sparse.einsum`, and the intermediate product is 3d, which sparse does not handle.

---

`sparse.kron` uses `coo` format, which is no good for working with the rows.  But working in the spirit of that function, I've worked out a function that iterates on the rows of `csr` format matrices.  Like `kron` and `bmat` I'm constructing the `data`, `row`, `col` arrays, and constructing a `coo_matrix` from those.  That in turn can be converted to other formats.

```
def test_iter(A, B):
    m,n1 = A.shape
    n2 = B.shape[1]
    Cshape = (m, n1*n2)
    data = np.empty((m,),dtype=object)
    col =  np.empty((m,),dtype=object)
    row =  np.empty((m,),dtype=object)
    for i,(a,b) in enumerate(zip(A, B)):
        data[i] = np.outer(a.data, b.data).flatten()
        #col1 = a.indices * np.arange(1,a.nnz+1) # wrong when a isn't dense
        col1 = a.indices * n2   # correction
        col[i] = (col1[:,None]+b.indices).flatten()
        row[i] = np.full((a.nnz*b.nnz,), i)
    data = np.concatenate(data)
    col = np.concatenate(col)
    row = np.concatenate(row)
    return sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row,col)),shape=Cshape)
```

With these small 2x2 matrices, as well as larger ones (e.g. `A1=sparse.rand(1000,2000).tocsr()`), this is about 3x faster than the version using `bmat`.  For large enough matrices it is better than dense `einsum` version (which can have memory errors).

Comment: Thanks! I thought of running kron and slicing the result but wasn't sure whether it would be a good idea since in my case it would generate a matrix with trillions of rows. Rewriting kron is a good idea. Will profile a few of the ideas you suggested and see what works best.

Comment: I've worked out a `kron` rewrite that gives 3x speedup compared to the earlier `bmat` calculation.

Comment: Thanks! Your rewritten test_iter function is indeed a lot faster.

One thing I am curious about: if the number of rows in the input matrices is increased, the CPU time increase is worse than linear. This seems strange because rows have no interaction which each other. Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Hi @hpaulj, I notice that your code (while working for the example above) doesn't always give the right results. For example, consider the case:
    A = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[0,1]]))
    B = scipy.sparse.csr_matrix(np.array([[0,5],[6,7],[0,1]]))
    test_iter(A,B).todense()  
gives:  

`matrix([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
        [18, 21, 24, 28],
        [ 0,  0,  1,  0]])`  

but it should give:  

`matrix([[ 0,  5,  0, 10],
        [18, 21, 24, 28],
        [ 0,  0,  0,  1]])`

I am taking the liberty of editing your post above to clarify this to other readers.

Comment: The problem is in ` a.indices * np.arange(1,a.nnz+1)`.  This works for a dense row.  I need to figure a different way to 'stretch' that list of indeices.

Comment: Turns out the correction is simpler than what I had before.

Answer (score 2):

A non-optimal way to do it is to kron separately for each row:

```
def my_mult(A, B):
    nrows = A.shape[0]
    prodrows = []
    for i in xrange(0, nrows):
        Arow = A.getrow(i)
        Brow = B.getrow(i)
        prodrow = scipy.sparse.kron(Arow,Brow)
        prodrows.append(prodrow)
    return scipy.sparse.vstack(prodrows)
```

This is approx 3x worse in performance than @hpaulj's solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26153147/special-kind-of-row-by-row-multiplication-of-2-sparse-matrices-in-python/26154881#26154881), as can be seen by running the following code:

```
A=scipy.sparse.rand(20000,1000, density=0.05).tocsr()
B=scipy.sparse.rand(20000,1000, density=0.05).tocsr()

# Check memory
%memit C1 = test_iter(A,B)
%memit C2 = my_mult(A,B)

# Check time
%timeit C1 = test_iter(A,B)
%timeit C2 = my_mult(A,B)

# Last but not least, check correctness!
print (C1 - C2).nnz == 0
```

**Results:**

hpaulj's method:

```
peak memory: 1993.93 MiB, increment: 1883.80 MiB
1 loops, best of 3: 6.42 s per loop
```

this method:

```
peak memory: 2456.75 MiB, increment: 1558.78 MiB
1 loops, best of 3: 18.9 s per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

hpauj's answer to my another post:

[How do i create interacting sparse matrix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59671759/how-do-i-create-interacting-sparse-matrix)

```
def test_iter2(A, B): 
    m,n1 = A.shape 
    n2 = B.shape[1] 
    Cshape = (m, n1*n2) 
    data = [] 
    col =  [] 
    row =  [] 
    for i in range(A.shape[0]): 
        slc1 = slice(A.indptr[i],A.indptr[i+1]) 
        data1 = A.data[slc1]; ind1 = A.indices[slc1] 
        slc2 = slice(B.indptr[i],B.indptr[i+1])  
        data2 = B.data[slc2]; ind2 = B.indices[slc2]  
        data.append(np.outer(data1, data2).ravel()) 
        col.append(((ind1*n2)[:,None]+ind2).ravel()) 
        row.append(np.full(len(data1)*len(data2), i)) 
    data = np.concatenate(data) 
    col = np.concatenate(col) 
    row = np.concatenate(row) 
    return sparse.coo_matrix((data,(row,col)),shape=Cshape)
```

It got 6 times faster.

```
In [536]: S0=sparse.random(200,200, 0.01, format='csr')                                                   
In [537]: S1=sparse.random(200,200, 0.01, format='csr')                                                   
In [538]: timeit test_iter(S0,S1)                                                                         
42.8 ms ± 1.7 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
In [539]: timeit test_iter2(S0,S1)                                                                        
6.94 ms ± 27 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```